# HTML img tag whose source is document on Google Drive, using Google Drive SDK / API

Tags: google-drive-api

Is this possible with the Google Drive SDK?:
Have an html document on Drive that loads images and videos whose source location is Drive, in offline mode? (My target platform is iOS.)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible with [Website publishing](https://developers.google.com/drive/publish-site). An image on the folderA can be accessible with
`https://googledrive.com/host/<IDOfFolderA>/imagename.jpg`.

Comment: That gets me closer, thanks, but I'd like to have that working in offline mode. You can make files in Drive available offline, and I'd like an offline website on iOS. So what I need is the url to the Drive folder on iOS, not a url that contains http.